# Why do I have to open and save excel once, before uploading

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, xlsx

I am using puppeteer to automate the process of extracting data and uploading into a system.

Using Node.js XLSX package, I have been able to generate the excel file, further step is to upload that generated file.

When I upload that file into another system, it recognises the file as empty, whereas, it has data in it. If I open the file manually and just press save without doing any changes and re-upload the file, than it works.

Why is that so? Why do I have to open and save it once and than the 3rd party system recognises it. Unfortunately, I dont have code level access of that system but I know its build on ASP.NET.

Not sure if this is a problem of Nodejs or puppeteer or that system where I am uploading the file.

If there can be a solution at Nodejs level, which can address this, that would be helpful

I have tried fixing column width just to see if thats a problem because of that. but it did not work.